# collectd plugin creation for openstack spawning time metrics

Tags: scripting, openstack, collectd

I have a script which gives back a second value how log it takes to spawn a specific size vm in openstack.

How can I use this second value to use in collectd? Where and waht I have to set?

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the exec plugin with a user different from root:

```
<Plugin exec>
  Exec "ansible:ansible" "/usr/share/collectd/collectd_spawningtest.sh"
</Plugin>
```

The script itself like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAME="${COLLECTD_HOSTNAME:-$(hostname -f)}"
INTERVAL="${COLLECTD_INTERVAL:-600}"

while sleep "$INTERVAL"
do
        LINTIME=$(cat /var/tmp/linspawntime)
        echo "PUTVAL $HOSTNAME/spawntime/time_offset-linspawn interval=$INTERVAL N:$LINTIME"
        WINTIME=$(cat /var/tmp/winspawntime)
        echo "PUTVAL $HOSTNAME/spawntime/time_offset-winspawn interval=$INTERVAL N:$WINTIME"
done
```